# What's the use of specifying the type of a HashSet when working with the generic Set interface?

Tags: java

If you instantiate a new HashSet, you usually use the Set interface to work with it afterwards. Just like

```
Set<T> set = new HashSet();
```

So what is the use of specifying the type of the HashSet explicitly, too? For example:

```
Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
```

I've seen it in quite a couple of books, but I can't think of any use at all. If you need access to the set, you'll work with the interface (which is already parameterized) anyway.

Comment: Just as an aside, in Java 7 there is the new diamond operator:  Set<T> set = new HashSet<>() which automatically sets the type.  In this example it only saves 1 character, but sometimes the generic type can itself be a parametrized type and be 30 characters long, so it saves a lot of typing in such a case.

Comment: @toto2 Worked for us. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you say this:

```
Set<T> set = new HashSet();
```

you'll get an unchecked conversion warning. The static type of `new HashSet()` is a raw HashSet, and converting from that to a generified type is potentially unsafe.

There are other circumstances where doing an assignment will cause type inference to take place. Calling a static method is the canonical example. eg:

```
Set<T> set = Collections.emptySet();
```

Java doesn't do inference on the `new` operator, however, as this would introduce an ambiguity into the language.

If you don't like the redundancy you can use a wrapper static method, and inference will take place. Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) does this, so you can say:

```
Set<T> set = Sets.newhashSet();
```

Answer (score 1):

It helps ensure type safety.  In your example, there really is no harm (besides the warning), but consider the following:

```
Set one = new HashSet();
one.add("haha");
Set<Integer> two = one;
```

In this case, because we were lazy with generic type parameters, we have ended up with a set of integers that contains a String.

Then, if you try to access the elements on the set, you will get a type cast error because a String is not an Integer.